# Sending an attachment email from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, email-attachments

i have an sql query code that send an attachment csv through email, and it was working well with no issues.
then suddenly it stopped working.
below is my piece of code , knowing that am using sql server 2016

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) , @File nvarchar(max) , @MsgBdy1 nvarchar(max)
SET @SQL ='
use MYDB
go
set nocount on 
select  x, Code , y , z  from table1  left join table2
on table1.a= table2.b'

 

 SET @File  = 'xyz'  + '' + cast(convert(date,getdate(),103)as nvarchar(50))   +  '.txt'
set @MsgBdy1 = CHAR(13)  + CHAR(13) + char(13) + N'this is the email'

 print @sql
 print  @file
EXEC MSDB.dbo.sp_Send_DBMail 
   @recipients= N'xyz@xyz.com',
   @Subject= N'abc' ,
   @copy_recipients= N'xyz@xyz.com',
   @blind_copy_recipients='N'xyz@xyz.com' ,
   @Body = @MsgBdy1,
   @profile_name = 'valid profile',
   @Query=@SQL,
   @Attach_Query_Result_As_File = 1,
   @query_result_header = 1,
   @exclude_query_output =1,
   @query_result_separator = '  ',
   @query_result_no_padding = 1,
   @Query_Attachment_Filename = @File
```

the dataset size is small , i tried almost every thing/
query returns no error , normal email is being recieved if i  set @Attach_Query_Result_As_File = 0,

any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: Have you check the [Database Mail log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/tools/troubleshoot-database-mail-issues) for any error messages ?

Comment: The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2023-07-14T09:25:21). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The operation has timed out.).  )

this is the message . although the query ends up in no time !!

Comment: The query might complete quickly but how big is the results file that it creates? How long does it take to transfer that data over the internet to your configured SMTP mail server? (Bear in mind that it's probably a base64 encoded attachment and so 33% bigger than you think it is.)

Comment: Why misuse SQL to send mails? That's a task for an application which can handle it far better and allows much simpler and clearer error handling. SQL's purpose is to fetch data, not to send mails.

Comment: even if i change the query to take only top 1 record , it is nt working

Comment: the problem is that your account isn#t allowed to sent emails this way, check if the email provider changed his system, to much more secure communication

Comment: You can't put `GO` in a `@query`. But it doesn't need to be there anyway.